# How to achieve only one card swipe at a time in swipe to dismiss action of flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to achieve only one card swipe at a time in a swipe to dismiss action of flutter?

Comment: Please, show us some relevant code you have up to now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Dismissible' widget for that.

```
new Dismissible (
    child: new Card(
        ...
    ),
    onDismissed:  (direction) {
    ...
    }
);
```